# printf strange behavior when printing char - LLDB debugger

Tags: c++, printf, lldb

While working with a static C++ library for my iOS Xcode project, I met a strange behavior with printf and Xcode LLDB debugger, sometimes my print results of `printf("%s", char*)` was the char concatenated with numbers or garbage characters. The attached image speaks for itself. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: A textual copy-and-paste of your code would be easier to read and to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work as expected. `%s` requires NUL-terminated string, that is, for a given `char*`, print anything until the first `'\0'`. You have to allocate 5 bytes and assign `a[4]=0;` if you want your array to be suitable for `%s`.

Comment: *Any* behavior would be "as expected". If you give `printf("%s", blah)` a pointer to an array that's not NUL-terminated, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The character array `a` needs to be terminated with a `'\0'` if you're printing it with a `%s` format specifier:

```
char * a = new char[5];

a[0] = 'i';
a[1] = 'p';
a[2] = 'o';
a[3] = 'd';
a[4] = '\0';

printf("word: %s\n", a);
```